# Loadrunner/PC file upload with pop-up TruClient

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

I have an app that has a GUI dialog that pops up a download window to attach a PDF to be sent.
Recording the scenario in TruClient, however does not open the download pop up, so I cannot upload a file. Does TruClient have an option to "turn on" pop ups and giving me the oportunity to actually upload (and record) a file?

Comment: not possible to record native filedialog according to HP support request

Comment: using truclient that is

Comment: The common file dialogs are not a part of actual IE or Firefox, which is the issue here.   The Print and Page setup are other examples of the common file dialog which would not be recorded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you won't be able to handle a pop up (modal window) in your script. But if you are using LR 11.52 TruClient for Firefox, if you browse and select a file, then the step will be recorded as **Set [path] on [object] filebox** with an Object role of filebox.

Comment: I made this work however the filedialog does not close whe n replaying Using Truclient 11.52 for IE howverer seems to close the filedialog. why different behavior?

Comment: How can I close this filedialog manually? it does not close itself during replay.Javascript function to say filedialog.close?